# 'constructor' is not a recognized attribute location

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

After trying to compile the following code:

```
public sealed class Program
{
    [constructor: CLSCompliant(false)]
    public Program()
    {
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> 'constructor' is not a recognized attribute location. Valid attribute locations for this declaration are 'method'. All attributes in this block will be ignored. [Console.NET]csharp(CS0658)

I know that there are the following locations are present: `assembly`, `module`, `method`, `parameter`, `return`, etc. So, my guess was that the `constructor` should be present as well (since we can have a constructor as a target for an attribute as well). But it seems that it is not the case here.

Also, I was not able to find a full list of the recognized attribute locations on the MSDN. So, that would be helpful if someone would provide a link to the list of the locations on the MSDN.

My guess about the presence of the `constructor` location was based after I met the following code sample in the **C# via CLR** book:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
[Serializable]
[DefaultMemberAttribute("Main")]
[DebuggerDisplayAttribute("Richter", Name = "Jeff", Target = typeof(Program))]
public sealed class Program
{
    [Conditional("Debug")]
    [Conditional("Release")]
    public void DoSomething() { }
    public Program()
    {
    }
    [CLSCompliant(true)]
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Show the set of attributes applied to this type
        ShowAttributes(typeof(Program));
        // Get the set of methods associated with the type
        var members =
        from m in typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMembers.OfType<MethodBase>()
        where m.IsPublic
        select m;
        foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
        {
            // Show the set of attributes applied to this member
            ShowAttributes(member);
        }
    }
    private static void ShowAttributes(MemberInfo attributeTarget)
    {
        var attributes = attributeTarget.GetCustomAttributes<Attribute>();

        Console.WriteLine("Attributes applied to {0}: {1}",
        attributeTarget.Name, (attributes.Count() == 0 ? "None" : String.Empty));
        foreach (Attribute attribute in attributes)
        {
            // Display the type of each applied attribute
            Console.WriteLine(" {0}", attribute.GetType().ToString());

            if (attribute is DefaultMemberAttribute)
                Console.WriteLine(" MemberName={0}",
                ((DefaultMemberAttribute)attribute).MemberName);
            if (attribute is ConditionalAttribute)
                Console.WriteLine(" ConditionString={0}",
                ((ConditionalAttribute)attribute).ConditionString);
            if (attribute is CLSCompliantAttribute)
                Console.WriteLine(" IsCompliant={0}",
                ((CLSCompliantAttribute)attribute).IsCompliant);
            DebuggerDisplayAttribute dda = attribute as DebuggerDisplayAttribute;
            if (dda != null)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(" Value={0}, Name={1}, Target={2}",
 dda.Value, dda.Name, dda.Target);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

And the output of this program is the following:

```
Attributes applied to Program:
 System.SerializableAttribute
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplayAttribute
 Value=Richter, Name=Jeff, Target=Program
 System.Reflection.DefaultMemberAttribute
 MemberName=Main

Attributes applied to DoSomething:
 System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute
 ConditionString=Release
 System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute
 ConditionString=Debug

Attributes applied to Main:
 System.CLSCompliantAttribute
 IsCompliant=True
 System.STAThreadAttribute

Attributes applied to .ctor: None
```

The output makes it clear that a constructor is treated differently from the class and method. And since there are locations `class` and `method`, the `constructor` location is expected by me to be present as well.

I need this solely for the learning purposes.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you *want* that code to do? (Obviously there is no such syntax... but that makes it very hard to understand what you want to achieve).

Comment: Prefixes are only required when the attribute target is not directly addressable. The attribute is already applied to the constructor, so a prefix is unnecessary.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I want to understand why there is no location like `constructor`. In the question I explain why I am expecting the `constructor` location to be present. Thank you.

Comment: For contrast, C# has a `return:` prefix because the return type cannot be directly addressed, but VB doesn't have one because the return type can be addressed directly.

Comment: @qqqqqqq There is no `constructor` location because it isn't needed.  You apply the attribute right before the constructor.

Comment: @madreflection, does it mean that since it is impossible to address a constructor indirectly there is no need for such a location as `constructor`, so it was not added?

Comment: Ok. If the explanation of the absence of the `constructor` location is that it is impossible to address a  constructor indirectly, then why do we have the `method` location? Is it possible to address a method indirectly (meaning in a way different from a constructor addressing)?

Comment: Basically your question is "why when I add attribute on constructor there is no need to add additional information to figure out that I put attribute on the constructor?"... Or you think there are some other cases when one could use such attribute so it is not clear what it applies to?

Comment: @qqqqqqq The list of available targets is on the [MSDN page on attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, my question is definitely not the first. After the comments were added it is not clear for me why would we need the `method` location and don\`t need the `constructor` location. Is `method` location an extra location?

Comment: @madreflection attribute on auto-property could be for method, property or field - it *may* be useful (or required by some coding style) to clarify which one it needs to be applied to... But I never seen `method:` used too - so totally agree that better to skip it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, oh. Thank you a lot. The case with the auto-property proves that the `method` location is useful. While there are no useful cases for a `constructor` location. That is what I was looking for along with the @Amy`s MSDN link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute targets list  present in two places:

- limit what an attribute can be applies to (via [AttributeUsageAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/attributeusage))
- disambiguate what the attribute applies to in each  particular case (via ["Attribute targets
  "](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/))

So why we'd have "method" but not "constructor" targets (my interpretation, I'm not aware of an official reasoning):

- "method" applies to methods and properties. It includes constructor as a special variation of a method. So there is a way to allow an attribute to be used on a constructor and not on an assembly or a field.
- when attribute applied to a constructor there is no other possible choices for default "method" target as a constructor matches only "method" option from the list of targets (unlike auto-property for example where attribute can be considered as targeting "method" or "property" or even "field")
- presumably there is no useful case where attribute must be restricted to just constructors.

Side note: since attributes by themselves generally don't do anything attribute targets are mainly to limit potential cases where attribute is set but impacts nothing. If you want to "target" just constructors some good naming may be enough. If you really want to limit to just constructors you can check all loaded types for improper use of your custom attribute at startup/first need to check for your custom attribute.